# I'm trying to check if a value is classified as a boolean or not, and i don't understand why my code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, boolean

**Check if a value is classified as a boolean primitive. Return true or false.**

Boolean primitives are true and false.

```
function booWho(bool) {
     return bool;
    }
    booWho(null);
```

**This are the tests:**

```
booWho(true) should return true.
Waiting:booWho(false) should return true.
Waiting:booWho([1, 2, 3]) should return false.
Waiting:booWho([].slice) should return false.
Waiting:booWho({ "a": 1 }) should return false.
Waiting:booWho(1) should return false.
Waiting:booWho(NaN) should return false.
Waiting:booWho("a") should return false.
Waiting:booWho("true") should return false.
Waiting:booWho("false") should return false.
```

**My tries:**

```
function booWho(bool) {
      return (bool == true||false)
    }
    booWho(null);

  
    function booWho(bool) {
      return (bool == true|| bool == false)
    }
    booWho(null);
```

this two gives me a problem with this test: `booWho(1)` should return false

```
function booWho(bool) {
      return (bool === true||false)
    }
    booWho(null);
```

this one gives me a problem with this test: `booWho(false)` should return true.

I ended up passing with `typeof`, but i have no idea why the others are giving errors, thanks in advanced

Comment: I mean, `typeof bool === 'boolean'` will do the basic trick...

Comment: The `||` operator does not work the way some of your tests expect it to. If you don't want `typeof`, then comparing `bool` to `true` and `false` with `===` will work.

Comment: But i don't understand why the `| |` doesn't work. When i was learning about it I was told it was a simpler/shorter way, but in some cases it works, but not in others, do you have a article or a recommendation for me to learn about why is that? Thanks!

Comment: @Meigu I hope you understood the `strict equality`  and what `falsy` and `truthy` values are. For the question why `bool === true || false` is working, actually is not working, it just work in the case where `bool` is `true` but if it's `false` or any other value it won't work, and that's because the expression is just `a || b`  where `a`  is  `bool === true` and `b`=`false`, so when one of  `a` or `b` is `true`  it will be `true`, in your case when `bool === true` is `true`, so if you test with `bool=false`, this won't work.I hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Use strict equality to prevent type coercion and separate the checks to `true` and `false`:

```
function booWho(bool) {
  return bool === true || bool === false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last try is close but you need to check for [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) using a triple equal (`===`) because non-boolean values can be [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) or `falsy` as well. `===` prevents implicit conversion.

```js
function booWho(bool) {
  return bool === true || bool === false;
}

console.log(booWho(true));
console.log(booWho(false));
console.log(booWho(null));
console.log(booWho([]));
console.log(booWho({}));
console.log(booWho(() => void 0));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know about truthy or falsy values, thanks a lot for the info. I was breaking my head thinking why it randomly decided not to work in some cases.  Do you know why `bool === true || false ` work? i thought it was the same but shorter that `bool === true || bool === false` Thanks again!

Comment: No it's not just shorter syntax but has a different meaning. I suggest doing some research on how the [*logical or operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) ( `||` ) works.